# Dynamic value for Transformer parameter

Tags: xslt

I'm building an XML transformer and I need to pass parameters into the stylesheet while the transformation is happening.

The problem is that one XML file can have more than one elements that needs a different UUID for example.

```
transformer.setParameter("uuid", "'3234343-3434343-343434343-3434343434'");
```

It there are way of passing a dynamic variable so each element in the XML will end up with a different UUID?

This is not the only parameter I'm passing. I'll have to look up data from external databases as well and feed that into the stylesheet.

Can I pass an array or a hash table if I pre-populate it or maybe ?

Or do I have to approach it with a whole different way? If so what is the best way of doing this?

Many thanks

Comment: @L4zl0w: You can pass any XPath 1.0 data type (or XDM data type in XSLT 2.0) like a node set instance.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thank you! I'll check what the XDM data types are.

Comment: @L4zl0w: [XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model (XDM) (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/)

Comment: The UID I managed to sort out with 

<xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/> in the xsl file.

Comment: I still find it hard to believe that the transformation that I'm trying to do: 1.) use a stylesheet file to transform 2.) look-up data from an external database and insert it into the final xml cannot be done in one step. As far as I understand I have to do the 1st step, save the xml, then do the 2nd by opening the saved xml and insert the lookup data before saving the xml again. Is there no way to do it in one step?

Comment: @L4zl0w: I think you are describing the requeriments for XQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UID I managed to sort out with `<xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>` in the xsl file.